# Remapped Function beginning with Underscore in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Codeigniter asks to use `_functions()` in controllers so that no one can access them from url. Now, I have a controller named `Profile` and have a `_remap()` function so that I can take any input in the form of `http://example.com/profile/asdf` .. So, whenever I call the url, the `_remap()` function takes the `asdf` as input and works on it.
Now for a special case, I have to input a name that starts with an underscore. Like `http://example.com/profile/_asdf`, which for now, generates a 404, as Codeigniter doesnt allow _ in front of method name in URL.

How to overcome this?

Comment: Is it really necessary to use the underscore? CI sees that as a private function (afaik is also a convention)

Comment: Yes, it was necessary. Anyway, Solved it. Posting the solution. :)

Comment: You should probably add it as answer or close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Solution**

Actually Codeigniter has a url validation function that generates 404 when it encounters an underscore in front of the url. I just hacked that function a bit.
In the file `/system/core/Router.php`, there is a function named `_set_request()`. Its first line was
`$segments = $this->_validate_request($segments);`

I just hacked that $segments variable, replaced all underscore with a dash(-).
`$segments = $this->_validate_request(str_replace("_", "-", $segments));`

And in my `_remap()` function, replaced them back. This was no private function got called and I got my work done. `:)`